# twrp flash successful but stuck at "recovery is not seandroid enforcing"

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, twrp, odin

when i try to flash **twrp**  odin says "**PASS**", but when I attempted to reboot into recovery mode, my phone froze on the 'Samsung Galaxy Grand prime' screen with a message in small red text at the top saying "RECOVERY IS NOT SEANDROID ENFORCING".

i have flashed and used twrp recovery before and i re-installed stock ROM which replaced my twrp but now im having this issue.

please help me why it happens and how to fix?